# Formatted SD card not showing up in Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sd-card

I've just formatted an SD card using the MiniTool Partition Wizard, and now it is no longer recognised in Windows. Windows plays the sounds when it is either removed or added, but it doesn't show up as a disk in Explorer. There's no errors with the SD card reader either (which is an internal laptop one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix by using this guide, which has a step by step guide to formatting your SD card via cmd:

https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-format-sd-dead-cards

I followed this through, and despite it taking a long time to reformat it managed to set it to NTFS after about 2-3 hours. Then it came up as normal in Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Windows have issues automatically mounting SD card with custom partitioning, please use [this guide](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/change-drive-letter-in-windows-10.html) to manually assign drive letter(s) to your partition(s).